# Button click not working when in presence of single Tap gesture

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have view hierarchy as follows

MyViewController --> ScrollView(added via IB) --> ImageView (+ zooming there) ---> button added on **image View**(added via code)

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]];
[scroll addSubview:imageView];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(660, 120, 40, 40);

[myButton setTitle:@"10" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(asiaPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[myButton setEnabled:YES];
[imageView addSubview:myButton];
```

later on in view controller, i defined selector as

```
-(void) asiaPressed:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"asiaPressed clicked");
```

}

But it is never going inside selector..

Pls help...i guess it is very basic error..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled property set to NO by default so it (and its subviews) does not receive touch events. You need to set that property to YES manually:

```
...
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
...
```

P.S. You also mention gesture recognizer in question title, however have not posted any code with it - so if it present it may also cause the problems, but the problem is most likely is what I described above

Comment: you can also set this attribute in Interface Builder (IB).